# When I run the face recognition code, I get the following errors

Tags: raspbian, opencv

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.1-dev) /home/pi/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:610: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvNamedWindow'

Installation and recompilation errors based on prompts cannot be resolved. Failure to install pkg-config using compiler
```

Comment: You need to install the required packages for UI support in OpenCV. Are you running rasbian or something else ?

Comment: @onion The question has the [raspbian] tag.

Comment: I run the code in the raspberry pie, install the software according to the error prompt, and recompile and install opencv, which is still compiling.

Comment: I confirm that libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config are installed and that opencv is compiled and installed again. The above errors in running the code have not been resolved!